# Setting up a SQL Membership Provider and attaching the MDF file in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-express, mdf

I'm trying to set up a SQL Membership Provider for an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and I'm having problems setting up the tables and stored procedures in the database.  I've tried attaching both the applications current database and a blank database to my local SQLEXPRESS instance (using SSEUtil) and then running the aspnet_regsql wizard against them.  When I detach the mdf file and try to load it in Visual Studio 2008, the data connection in the server explorer shows that the database has no tables or stored procedures.

Am I missing a step or something here? I've been having a heap of trouble with compatibility between Visual Studio and SQLEXPRESS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized the database wasn't being attached properly.  Using SQL Server Management Studio to attach the mdf file fixed the problem.